# How to Adjust the Position of the Page Number When No-header Command is Invoked

Tags: macros, page-numbering, fancyhdr, algorithms, vertical-spacing

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}

% Algorithm to put page number at bottom of page
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% definitions for \pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\emph{\large \thepage}}
% Same for \pagestyle{plain} - used for first chapter pages.
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\emph{\large \thepage}}
}
\fancypagestyle{nohead}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\emph{\large \thepage}}
}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
\begin{document}
\LARGE
\thispagestyle{nohead}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

with output

[image]

QUESTION: How may I adjust the position of the page number that is affected by the `\thispagestyle{nohead}` command? In this case (pg. 1), I would like to increase the vertical space between the last line and the page number. A global solution would be preferable.

Comment: You could use something like `\fancyfoot[C]{\raisebox{-1cm}{\emph{\large \thepage}}}`. Another option is to increase `\footskip`, like `\setlength{\footskip}{1cm}` .

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Yes, the `\footskip` suggestions work quite nicely. Perhaps you will consider converting your comments into an answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. Increase `\footskip`, like `\setlength{\footskip}{1cm}`
2. Use something like `\fancyfoot[C]{\raisebox{-1cm}{\emph{\large \thepage}}}`

Comment: Thank you for converting your helpful comments into an answer.